# How to display loading or IsBusy icon while login or between other activity is performed

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to display the loading icon `(IsBusy)` to display efficiently while while login into the app and should disappear after successful login. Here in my case, its not happening at all.

In the `finally` step, if set to `IsBusy = true`, then I can see that gets displaying (*screen shot added for that*), but that is not I want. I would like to it display for a small fraction of time while login into the app and it should go away once after successful login.

*note:* For all the else condition I have set to `IsBusy=false`

```
<ActivityIndicator x:Name="activityIndicator" IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"></ActivityIndicator>

public MainPage()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       this.BindingContext = this;
       this.IsBusy = false;
    }

public async void Button_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.IsBusy = true;
            string emailText = emailEntry.Text;
            string passwordText= passwordEntry.Text; 
            if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(emailEntry.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(passwordEntry.Text))
            {
                if(ValidateEmail(emailText) == true)
                {
                    int count = (from x in conn.Table<PlayerDetails>().Where(x => x.Email == emailText) select x).Count();
                    if (count!= 0)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                           List<PlayerDetails> myList = (from x in conn.Table<PlayerDetails>().Where(x => x.Email == emailText && x.Password == passwordText) select x).ToList();
                            if(myList.Count() > 0)
                            {
                              // do the login stuff here.....
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                this.IsBusy = false;
                                await DisplayAlert("Notification", "No such email or password", "Cancel");

                            }

                        }
                        catch (NullReferenceException ex)
                        {
                          if(ex!=null)
                            Debug.WriteLine("Something is thrown ! " + e.ToString());
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            IsBusy = false;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.IsBusy = false;
                        await DisplayAlert("Notification", "Unable to find the user details", "Cancel");
                    } 
                }
                else
                {
                    this.IsBusy = false;
                    await DisplayAlert("Notification", "Email is not a valid one", "Cancel");
                }   
            }
            else
            {
                this.IsBusy = false;
                await DisplayAlert("Notification","Input details cannot be blank", "Cancel");
            }
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested your code and I found it works.

The reason why you can't see the `ActivityIndicator` is the code executed very fast and you can't even see the process of `ActivityIndicator` changing from `running` to `not running`.

If you add a little delay after setting `IsBusy = true`, you will find it really works:

```
 this.IsBusy = true;
 Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000));    
 string emailText = emailEntry.Text;
 string passwordText= passwordEntry.Text;
```

Comment: Hua, I have added 5000 milliseconds and i am not able to see the IsBusy loading.  `Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000));`  I can see a green line under the above code line and says .."Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed..

Comment: Then I have added `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));` I can see that IsBusy loading icon running

Answer (score 0):

I am almost certain that your `MainPage` is not implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. Try changing you MainPage implementation so it'll look like this:

```
public class MainPage : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool isBusy;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get => isBusy;
        set
        {
            isBusy = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsBusy));
        }
    }

    //public bool IsBusy
    //{
    //  get => isBusy;
    //  set { SetProperty(ref isBusy, value); }
    //}

    public MainPage()
    {
    }

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T backingStore, T value, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "",
        Action onChanged = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingStore, value))
        {
            return false;
        }

        backingStore = value;

        onChanged?.Invoke();

        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }


    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        var changed = PropertyChanged;
        if (changed == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        changed(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment regarding code:

- I strongly recommend you should put `INotifyPropertyChanged` in a base class or ViewModel
- You can use choose which IsBusy implementation is better. They are doing the same but with different syntax.

One more thing to add:
Take a look at MVVM pattern. With MVVM approach you can split View from logic (will should be in ViewMode). In your case the BindingContext will be ViewModel.
What's more, take a look at PropertyChanged.Fody nuget for `INotifyPropertyChanged` classes.

Comment: @Iawiluk What should I pass in `CallerMemberName` ?

Comment: I have changed as per you suggested, I am not able to see the difference. I can't see the `IsBusy` loading.

Answer (score 0):

The best loader for xamarin forms is this : https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs

```
void UserLogin()
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading ("Loading ...", MaskType.Black));
    Task.Run (() => {
        //add Login method here
    }).ContinueWith (result => Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {
        UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading ();
    }
}));
```